# can't pass data to my controller from views

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to pass 5 optional values to my controller

```
    public class ActivityManagementTwoFiltersModel
    {
    public string timeFilter { get; set; } = "Last 30 days";
    public int numberOfItemsToReturn { get; set; } = 25;
    public DateTime? dateStart { get; set; } = null;
    public DateTime? dateEnd { get; set; } = null;
    public Guid? districtId { get; set; } = null;
    }
```

my controller is like this

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> ActivityManagementTwo( ActivityManagementTwoFiltersModel filters)
```

my view:

```
  @{using (Html.BeginForm("ActivityManagementTwo", "CallCenter", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "ActivityTwoForm" }))
    {
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="float:right;">
                <div class="dateWrapper">@{Html.RenderPartial("_DateFilter"); }</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 8px;">
            <div class="col-md-3 ActivityManagementTwoHeader" style="font-size:12px; font-weight: bold">
                Displaying Results @Model.Count() of @Model.Count()
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                Items per page:
                @Html.DropDownList("numberOfItemsToReturn", new List<SelectListItem> {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "25", Text= "25"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "50", Text= "50"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "100", Text= "100"},
                })                   
            </div>           
        </div>
    }
}
```

I want to hit my controller from the main view or partial view whenever one of the dropdown menu's is changed. I tried a JS function but it didn't submit the values

```
    document.getElementById("numberOfItemsToReturn").addEventListener("change", function () {
    document.getElementById("ActivityTwoForm").submit();
})
```

didn't work. How can I pass the controller the parameters from the drop down menu's on change?

edit: Here's my partial view. The partial View fields are being sent , it's only the numberOfItemsToReturn that are not

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:right; vertical-align: top; width: 160px">
                Time filter:
            </td>
            <td style="display:inline-block; width:150px" >
                <input id="radio1" name="radioToggle" type="radio"> Recent
                <select id="timeFilter" name="timeFilter" >
                    <option value="Last 30 days">at least 18</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                <input id="radio2" name="radioToggle" class="radioTimeFilter" type="radio"> Date Range
                <div id="dateContent" class="radio-content" style="display:none;">
                    <input id="txtDateOneFilter" type="text" style="width: 70px;" placeholder="Start Date" name="dateStart"/>&nbsp;to&nbsp;
                    <input id="txtDateTwoFilter" type="text" style="width: 70px;" placeholder="End Date" name="dateEnd" />
                </div>
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: change FormMethod from Get to Post

Comment: I've tried that. Still doesn't send the data. I should use post because there's no query string for get?

Comment: put a debug on the controller method and check if its hit

Comment: the controller hits but it uses the default values for any optional parameters. I've tried just setting the optional params with (numberOfItemsToReturn = 25) and I've tried making a class with default values for the controllers parameter

Comment: you know it's only the "numberOfItemsToReturn " that is not passing correctly is it because it's an int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `[HttpPost]` to the action

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ActivityManagementTwo( ActivityManagementTwoFiltersModel filters)
```

then fix your form

```
@{using (Html.BeginForm("ActivityManagementTwo", "CallCenter", FormMethod.Post))
```

Add Submit button to the form to test it

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
```

Comment: Well I was hoping to use the same controller for the initial page load too. I have a seperate partial for navigation & pagination so this controller sort of just returns a list<objects> . Do I just need to seperate them into intial load action. I tried changing actionresult to viewresult

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.DropDownList(m => m.numberOfItemsToReturn, new List<SelectListItem> {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "25", Text= "25"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "50", Text= "50"},
```

Comment: Dear Jonathan, please provide some explanation to the code, Code-Only answers are usually seen a bit weird on SoF.